# Application giving "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" error while trying to run

Tags: android

I have developed an android application.But when i try to run the code its shows error message

```
Description Resource   Path             Location   Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Conversion to Dalvik   VMSApplication   Unknown    Android Packaging Problem
format failed with 
error 1
```

Has someone faced this problem before...

Thanks in advance

--

```
[2011-06-24 16:34:45 - VMSApplication] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
[2011-06-24 16:34:45 - VMSApplication] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2011-06-24 16:34:46 - VMSApplication] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2011-06-24 16:34:46 - VMSApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what version of the android SDK you are running or what platform. You might try this solution for Windows 7 Solution:

Confirmed the problem is caused by ProGuard command line in the file
[Android SDK Installation Directory]\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat

Edit the following line will solve the problem:

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```

to

```
call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to clean and restart the eclipse,this may help.Also check out these links [link1](http://www.filsa.net/2009/06/13/re-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1/) and [link2](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error because I was trying to build when connected to emulator