# Conversion to Dalvik failed with error 1 after updating ADT 16.0.1 to ADT 18.0 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

This is really mysterious. Till now my all android projects in the workspace were working fine when ADT was 16.0.1. 
I decided to update it to ADT 18.0 and restarted the Eclipse in order to take changes in effect. But to my surprise, when I tried to run the project, its giving me

**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1** 
**Unknown   Android Packaging Problem**

Also its automatically created "Android Dependencies" in my project.
Can anyone please tell me the fastest working solution for this?
Its damm urgent.. :(
I also made uninstall of ADT 18 and tried to install ADT 16, but its not working. 
Please suggest me the way so that I can get back to work normally in my workspace

Comment: See this one..!! http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220356/1321873

Comment: Try to Clean and build the all the project and rebuild it again.It may help you..

Comment: @Mike and Deepa: I followed the above article and applied Clean Build to my all the projects. But none.. :(

Comment: @Rajesh I see the link you posted here. Also tried to edit the proguard.bat, but to my surprise, there is not a line which starts with keywork 'call', so I did not apply changes to it. Any other solution?

Comment: @YuAndroid, try replacing the line `java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*` with `java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`

Comment: @Rajesh its not working. I applied above changes and restarted eclipse also to see the effects

Answer (score 0):

i also got problems after the update to ADT 18, i must reinstall my android eclipse plugin. MAybe this can also help you

Comment: You can see in my question buddy that I uninstalled and then re-install the ADT, but its giving still the same error..